# Calling array with variable size as parameter

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, function-parameter

I was trying to make a program in which the user decides the dimensions of a 2-D array. 
I'm getting an error on the function definition while compiling. Why is this wrong and what would be the correct way to do it?

I'm using the Dev-C++ 5.7.1 compiler (if that's relevant).

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int R=0,C=0;                 

void func(int);

int main() {
    cin>>R>>C;
    int array[C][R];
                      // DO STUFF HERE
    func(array);
                      // DO SOME MORE STUFF
    return 0;
}

void func(int arr[][R]) {  
                     // DO STUFF HERE
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ISO-C++ forbids VLAs.  To dynamically allocate an array you'll either need to do some raw pointer tricks or use a [vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of vectors.

vector of vectors approach:

```
std::cin >> R >> C;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> array(R, std::vector<int>(C));
```

The signature for `func` then becomes (const correctness may be different)

```
void func(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& v);
```

The above is the easier, more maintainable, safer, shorter solution.

---

With pointers and pointers to pointers you can do it but it becomes more complicated, and you need to `delete` everything that you `new`

```
int R, C;
std::cin >> R >> C;
int **array = new int*[R]; // allocates space for R row pointers
for (int i = 0; i < R; ++i) {
    array[i] = new int[C]; // for each row, allocate C columns
}

func(R, C, array);

//then delete everything
for (int i = 0; i < R; ++i) {
    delete [] array[i]; // delete all of the ints themselves
}
delete [] array; // delete the row pointers.
```

with the signature for func being

```
void func(int r, int c, int **arr);
```

again, vector of vectors will be a lot easier on you.

Answer (score 1):

An array can be located in two different memory regions - on the stack, or on the heap.
Array like you specified, is located on the stack.

```
int array[SIZE];
```

when an array is located on the stack, the compiler needs to know in advance what is its size, therefor SIZE must be a constant expression (known at compile time), and sometimes a defined value (set using #define SIZE 10).
if you want to create an array of unknown size (will be determined in runtime), you need to create the array on the heap, like this:

```
int **array = new int*[C];
for(int i = 0;i<C; i++)
  array[i] = new int[R];
```

later on, you must remember to delete everything you dynamically allocated (everything you used new on)

```
for(int i = 0;i<C; i++)
  delete[] array[i];
delete[] array;
```

note the use of delete[], because we are deleting an array (array is an array of arrays of ints, array[i] is an array of ints)

Comment: prefer `enum { SIZE = 10 };` or in C++11 `constexpr std::size_t SIZE = 10;` because it's actually part of C++ (as opposed to the preprocessor substitution) and they have scope.

Comment: it's not that `SIZE` must be `const`, it's that it must be a *constant expression*.  You can have a const variable where the value is not known at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend passing in a pointer to the array, and two variables for R and C.  Then it's up to you to make sure you use pointer math correctly to stay within the bounds of the array.
Otherwise set this up as a template, but you'll still probably need to know the sizes of R & C.

Comment: How exactly do you pass a pointer to a 2-D array as a parameter? And how can you convert it back to a 2-D array within the function? (I'm relatively new to C++) Thanks!

Comment: I think Ryan covered it pretty well in the second part of his answer.  Inside the function just use array[x][y].  This is the C answer on how to do it.  The first part of Ryan's answer is the more proper C++ way to do it.